# how to create html otomatic in template vue file

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i want to create html inside template in vue, but i have to create manual,i using vscode editor

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
      <h1>hellow word</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  props: {
    msg: String
  }
}
</script>
```

in code above , even only create h1 i have to make open tag html dan create close, than take time
any body have solution

i have install many snippet but all is not working

Comment: You can use interpolation, like `<h1>{{ msg }}</h1>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install plugin [Vetur for Visual studio code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur) and make sure your file extension is .vue